# Showing that $~\hom_G(V,\bigoplus U)=\bigoplus\hom_G(V,U)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Today when asking for help to prove a proposition I got the following hint: $~\hom_G(V,\bigoplus U)=\bigoplus\hom_G(V,U)$.
$V$ is irreducible and $\bigoplus$ is finite.

However, I cannot see how to prove this. Also, I cannot see, how this fits with the following example:

Let $L(X,Y)$ denote a linear transformation from $X$ to $Y$.

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be such that any $v \in V$ has the form

\begin{equation} v = (x,0). \end{equation}

Let $W \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be such that any $w \in V$ has the form

\begin{equation} w = (0,y). \end{equation}

Let $T \in L(\mathbb{R},V \oplus W)$ be such that $Ta = (a,a)$.

But then $T \notin L(\mathbb{R},V)$, as $T(1) = (1,1) \notin V$.
Similarly $T \notin L(\mathbb{R},W)$, as $T(1) = (1,1) \notin W$.
Hence $T \notin L(\mathbb{R},V) \oplus L(\mathbb{R},W).$

Where is my mistake?

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: What's $\hom_G$? If you're talking about $G$-modules, then the statement is wrong, unless you have more hypotheses on $V$, or the direct sum is assumed to be finite.

Comment: Let $A\colon x \mapsto (x,0)$, and $B\colon x\mapsto (0,x)$. Then $A\in L(\mathbb{R},V), B\in L(\mathbb{R},W)$, and $T = A + B$.

Comment: Sorry! I have added that $V$ is irreducible and that $\bigoplus$ is finite.

Comment: Well, $(1,1)$ isn't on the $x$-axis, and it isn't on the $y$-axis ... and that's supposed to imply that $(1,1)$ isn't a point on the plane?? (This is the mistake.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any category we have $\hom(x,\prod_i y_i) \cong \prod_i \hom(x,y_i)$. This is essentially a reformulation of the universal property. In the category of $G$-modules finite products coincide with finite direct sums. Done.